# compile error occured in thrust/type_traits.h

Tags: cuda, thrust

I just try to add trust::sort in my cuda code, but nvcc tell me that:

```
type_traits.h(322): error C2660: 'test' : function does not take 1 arguments
type_traits.h(322): error C2866:'thrust::detail::tt_detail::is_convertible_sfinae<From,To>::value' : a const static data member of a managed type must be initialized at the point of declaration

type_traits.h(355): error C2057: expected constant expressiontype_traits.h(363): error C2975: '__v' : invalid template argument for 'thrust::detail::integral_constant', expected compile-time constant expression
type_traits.h(363): error C2975: '__v' : invalid template argument for 'thrust::detail::integral_constant', expected compile-time constant expression
```

I have search for that but there seems no one get the same problem as me

The part of my code that about thrust:

```
#include <thrust\sort.h>

struct prepare_struct 
{
float xp;
float yp;
float zp;
float xs;
float ys;
float zs;
float sep;
int idSrc_idEve;
};

int compare_sort(prepare_struct &a, prepare_struct &b){ return a.sep > b.sep;}

void func(...){
...

prepare_struct* sPos_d;
checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc((void**)&sPos_d, n*sizeof(prepare_struct) ) );

//a kernel that will fill sPos_d

thrust::sort(sPos_d, sPos_d + n, compare_sort);

...
}
```

If I remove thrust::sort(), it could be compiled without error

I've tried thrust::device_vector, but it will get the same error

And raw_pointer_cast() will get the same error message too

Is this a bug inside thrust or nvcc?

or something wrong in my code?

environment:

win7 x64
vs 2010
cuda 5.0
sm_20

the device_vector version:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
void func(...){
...

thrust::device_vector<prepare_struct> sPos_dv(n_src_sta);
prepare_struct* sPos_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(sPos_dv.data());

//a kernel that will fill sPos_d

thrust::sort(sPos_dv.begin(),sPos_dv.end(),compare_sort);

...
}
```

Comment: Can you make an actual repro code? And why are you using `cudaMalloc` instead of Thrust's allocation? (you get the same error, but the `device_vector` version would be more logical)

Comment: If you want to know what is wrong with your code, you will actually have to show some. What you have posted thusfar is completely unhelpful.

Comment: I add the device_vector version. The code here is ALL my code that use thrust, and I can run whole program with std::sort() fine.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a post on Stack Overflow, make sure that you provide a **[Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)** (aka SSCCE). That would make life easier for other members who are trying to help you, and it would also help you find the actual error in your code. If your code is not compilable, provide an example that demonstrates the compilation issue.

As for your program, there must be things that you are not telling us. What you are trying to achieve is easily handled by Thrust without any error. Here is a modified (and completed) version of your program:

```
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

struct prepare_struct
{
  float xp;
  float yp;
  float zp;
  float xs;
  float ys;
  float zs;
  float sep;
  int idSrc_idEve;
};

struct prepare_struct_compare {
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator() (const prepare_struct& a, const prepare_struct& b)
  {
    return a.sep < b.sep;
  }
};

void initialize(thrust::host_vector<prepare_struct>& v)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    v[i].sep = v.size() - i;
}

void print(const thrust::host_vector<prepare_struct>& v)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    std::cout << " " << v[i].sep;
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main ()
{
  const int n = 10;

  // Initialize vector of prepare_struct on host
  thrust::host_vector<prepare_struct> vec_h(n);
  initialize(vec_h);
  std::cout << "Initial vector:" << std::endl;
  print(vec_h);

  // Copy vector to device
  thrust::device_vector<prepare_struct> vec_d = vec_h;

  // Sort on device
  thrust::sort (vec_d.begin(), vec_d.end(), prepare_struct_compare());

  // Copy result back to host
  thrust::host_vector<prepare_struct> res_h = vec_d;
  std::cout << "Final vector:" << std::endl;
  print(res_h);
}
```

Running this program gives us:

```
Initial vector:
 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Final vector:
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about SSCCE until you tell me. Thank you. I will edit my problem.

Comment: @BenC some suggestions: Works for me! is [not really an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid).  One of the drawbacks of a works for me answer is that folks may see that the question has an answer and move on.  In this case I think your response is spot-on, but it's just not well-suited to being an answer.  I struggle with this too.  My suggestion is to include most of your answer as a comment.  If you must provide code, use a service like pastebin.com and link to it.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I understand. I am still expecting some more information to edit and complete this answer though. The problem lies within the question which lacks the relevant information. When I am facing that kind of situation, I usually stick with comments, unless I see several important things that can help to solve the problem. Here, this seems like one of those debugging situations were a simple "from scratch" repro code could have helped him find the answer on his own. That kind of answer seems more useful than the actual (yet to be determined) cause of his problem, no?

Comment: Thank you for give me a way to find the answer. I write the second program for edit this question, but I found this program could be compiled. Then I found the problem is a line in another header: "extern "C" void test();". So I stop edit the question.